Merge 2 files once the conditions are met
I currently merge csv files using rename.bat which is placed and executed in the directory holding those csv's.
The resulting file is created from a group of files which are constantly imported from an external source.
copy *.csv Pal.ORD.txt /b && del * .csv && ren *.txt *.csv

The problem is that, if the resulting file is not scanned, then I will have the merged files in one core file and the new individual files coming up and the code will just not merge them all.
I was thinking of making improvements such as:
IF EXIST PAL.ORD.CSV (copy *.csv Pal.ORD.txt /b && del * .csv && ren *.txt *.csv /EXCLUDE: PAL.ORD.CSV)
ELSE (copy *.csv Pal.ORD.txt /b && del * .csv && ren *.txt *.csv)

The problem with this new code is that I am not sure if the syntax is is correct, (I don't know where to place the EXCLUDE as well, just not to fuse the main core file with the new individual ones) and I would still have an issue to solve: to merge the two final files created.
Should I also include a type  *.csv > concat_csv.txt at the end of the IF EXIST? This will also create an issue with the app that reads the file to import since it only allows csv files.

The syntax is not correct, and wherever you put EXCLUDE will be wrong.  Please open a Command Prompt window and run each of the following, reading the entire output from each: if /?,  copy /?,  del /?,  ren /?,  type /?.
